# How to add skin in a tabbed view navigator in ipad application?

Tags: iphone, apache-flex, ipad

I am working on a mobile(ipad) tabbed application where i want to add a skined tabbed view navigator.. currently im just uing buutons there.
how to add a skkied tabbed view navigator?
any codes or tutorials please share.
Thanks

Comment: Voting to close as user didn't do any research beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some brilliant documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html